# Llamada PHP a base de datos no almacena todos los datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Es un formulario de registro básico pero cuando reviso la base de datos en MySQL solo me guarda usuario, la clave hasheada y la fecha de creación. No me guarda el resto.

El sistema no me arroja ningún tipo de error, e incluso redirecciona a la página de login, pero en la base de datos sólo me arroja lo antes mencionado.

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (
  name, lastname, username, password, address1, address2, phonenumber, email
) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
    $stmt, "ssssssss", 
    $param_name, $param_lastname, $param_username, 
    $param_password, $param_address1, $param_address2, 
    $param_phonenumber, $param_email
  );

  $param_name = $name;
  $param_lastname = $lastname;
  $param_username = $username;
  $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  // Creates a password hash
  $param_address1 = $address1;
  $param_address2 = $address2;
  $param_phonenumber = $phonenumber;
  $param_email = $email;
  if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    // Redirect to login page
    header("location: login.php");
  }else{
    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
  }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Este es un ejemplo con un solo input pero todos los demás son iguales
pero con sus respectivos nombres y etiquetas.

```
<p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
  </div>
  <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.
```

Comment: Habría que ver de dónde está obteniendo los datos, o mejor dicho, sí las variables 
$name
$lastname
$address1
$address2
$phonenumber
$email
Tienen un valor.

Comment: dame un chance ya lo edito

Comment: ya lo extendí porque estaba muy corto

Comment: Imprime cada variable antes del insert y mira que valores tiene.

Comment: como puedo hacerlo ?

Comment: Haciendo print o echo

Comment: Eso de "despues de cargar la página para evitar fallos de seguridad y no usar GET" no tiene sentido, pon un ejemplo yse vera si es seguro o no.

Comment: un colega que antes trabajaba conmigo me dijo que usar post siempre era mejor porque no utiliza la cache del navegador y no permite al usuario usar el boton de atras del navegador porque ese codigo sera utilizado para un registro seguro con metodos de pagos y se requiere eso, y respondiendo tu otra pregunta luego de que presiono el boton submit en la base de datos solo se guarda el usuario la clave hasheada y la fecha de creacion

Comment: no es que sea mejor, es que es lo suyo. El verbo POST es utilizado para la creacion de elementos. El verbo GET es para la lectura, para obtener datos. Otra cosa es que se enseñe mal a la gente el uso de los verbos http.

Comment: acabo añadir al codigo el comando echo var_dump($_POST); y me da como resultado lo que pongo en los input creo que el problema debe estar en el envio hacia la base de datos

Comment: En las asignaciones de los datos que insertas, por ejemplo `$param_lastname = $lastname;`  no usas `$_POST` , así que ese var_dump poco nos indica si no muestras quien y cuando usa los valores de `$_POST`.

Comment: @Fly ya logre solventarlo me faltaba agregarle  trim($_POST) cuando pasaba los parametros a mysql como la pongo en resuelta ?

Comment: Escribe tu mismo cual fue la solución y la marcas como válida. Deberías explicar y mostrar el código donde usas ese `$_POST`, así como los datos y explicar porque `trim` solucionó el problema.

Answer (score 0):

esta fue la solucion

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssss", $param_name, $param_lastname, $param_username, $param_password, $param_address1, $param_address2, $param_phonenumber, $param_email, $referby);
            $param_name = trim($_POST["name"]);
            $param_lastname = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates apassword hash
            $param_address1 = trim($_POST["address1"]);
            $param_address2 = trim($_POST["address2"]);
            $param_phonenumber = trim($_POST["phonenumber"]);
            $param_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
            $param_referby = trim($_POST["referby"]);       
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
```

Comment: Explícala por favor pues no queda claro que cambiaste

Comment: cuando pase los parametros les pues un trim para obtener la string de la variable puesta en los inputs

Comment: edita tu respuesta y ahí coloca la explicación de forma detallada